# pressing UIBarButtonItem in UINavBar gives unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, uibarbuttonitem, unrecognized-selector

I have a view that implements a splitView controller.

I had to add TWO buttons to the Navigation controller. I added the first in UIBuilder but it would not let me add a second one so I did it in code.....

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view addSubview: _splitViewController.view];
    _splitViewController.delegate = _rightViewController;
    _leftViewController.delegate = _rightViewController;
    _rightViewController.leftView = _leftViewController;
   bbi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone   target:self action:@selector(done)];
    _navItem.leftBarButtonItem = bbi;
}
```

Where bbi was declared in the header as

```
@property (nonatomic, retain)     UIBarButtonItem * bbi;
```

with the matching definition above and synthesis.

I have declared the done method as 
    - (void)done:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender;

but when I click the done button I get the error

```
-[ConfigurationViewController done]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I have tried a number of things, with bbi declared locally instead of in the h file,
with done not being declared in the h file, having the done method expect an id instead, but no luck.

I am obviously doing something stupid. Any idea what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think done should have a colon after it if it is a method like this:

```
bbi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone   target:self action:@selector(done:)];
```

Comment: That seems to have fixed it - odd I looked at many similar examples and never saw the colon....

Comment: if your method takes a variable then it needs the colon. If it doesn't take any variables you don't use it.

Comment: @MySpecialPurpose: your answer is good, but as in your commetn *your method takes a variable*, i would say use proper term for that variable as *argument / parameter* :)

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Thanks for the advice! Just looked it up and read that 'argument' is the proper term when referring to the variables from the method call-in and 'parameter' is the proper term when referring to those variables inside the method. You learn something new every day!